# view code that was generated after compilation

Tags: java

How to look into code, that was generated after complilation?
I want to watch it and find how it was changed(because I particularly interested in type erasure).

I mean I can look into assembly code using `javap -c SomeClass.class`.

But how to look into generated code(with type erasure)?

Comment: You seem to be confused, type erasure is the opposite of code generation.

Comment: I meant I want to see how compiler changed generic types into raw types. Something like this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After short amount of time I found Java Decompiler `JD-GUI`. It seems that the thing I was looking for. Sorry if did not clarify the question properly.

Answer (score 0):

got to `Documents\NetBeansProjects\yourProjectName\build\classes\yourPackageName` here you will see all your .class files that was generated after compilation and open them using any text editor.

**Note:** the .class files might contain some binary data and you will see some strange symbols

**Note: an internal class will have the same name as its outer class but it will start with $ sign**